# Java to get max value from JDBC result set for a particular column

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to get maximum value of a column from a table using Java like below

```
rs.getString("MAX(COLUMN_NAME)");
```

but getting error as invlid column name. Is it possible to form the maximum value of a particular column at java code without below approach?

I have tried other way with

```
selectQuery = dbConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT MAX(COLUMN_NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME"); 
resultSet = selectQuery.executeQuery();
if (resultSet.next()) {
  System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1));
}
```

Have not succeeded with both approach.

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16382951/jdbc-selecting-the-max-value-from-an-access-table

Comment: try to use alias like this :
 `SELECT MAX(COLUMN_NAME) as max_value FROM TABLE_NAME` then get the result as `resultSet.getString("max_value")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried below code and it work:

```
    try{
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT MAX(COLUMN_NAME) FROM TABLE_NAME";
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);          
        //Extact result from ResultSet rs
        while(rs.next()){
            System.out.println("MAX(COLUMN_NAME)="+rs.getInt("MAX(COLUMN_NAME)"));              
          }
        rs.close();
       } catch(SQLException s){                     
            s.printStackTrace();
         }
```